# Do we need to care about target variable distribution in train and validation set in regression problem?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In a classification problem, we care about the distribution of the labels in train and validation set. In `sklearn`, there is `stratify` option in `train_test_split` to ensure that the distribution of the labels in train and validation set are similar.

In a regression problem, let's say we want to predict the housing price based on a bunch of features. Do we need to care about the distribution of the housing price in train and validation set?

If yes, how to we achieve this in `sklearn`?

Answer (score 0):

Forcing features to have similar distributions in your training and in your validation set assumes highly trusting the data you have to be representative of the data you will encounter in real life (*ie.* in a production environment), which is often not the case.

Also, doing so may virtually increase your validation score, compared to your test score.

Instead of adjusting feature distributions in train and validation sets, I would suggest you to perform cross-validation (in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)), which may be more representative of a testing situation.

Answer (score 0):

This [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920052289.do) ('A. Geron, *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow*, O'Reilly, 2017) provides an excellent introductory discussion of this in chapter 2. To paraphrase:

Generally for large datasets you don't need to perform stratified sampling: You training set *should* be a fair representation of the range of observed instances (there are of course exceptions to this). For smaller datasets you could introduce sampling bias (I.e., disproportionately recording data from only a particular region of the expected range of target attributes) if you performed random sampling and stratified sampling is properly required.

Practically, you will need to create a new *categorical* feature by binning this continuous feature. You can then perform stratified sampling of this categorical feature. Make sure to remove this new categorical feature before training your data!

However, to do this you will  need to have a good understanding of your features, I doubt there will be much point in performing stratified sampling of features of weak predictive power. I guess it could even do harm if you introduce some unintentional bias in the data by performing non-random sampling.

**Take home message:**

My instinct is that stratified sampling of a continuous feature should always be information and understanding lead. I.e, if you know a feature is a strong predictor of the target variable and you also know the sampling across its values is not uniform, you probably want to perform stratified sampling to make sure the range of values are properly represented in both the training and validation set.